# Counting in jquery Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I seem to have trouble calculating some numbers together. When I want to use:

```js
for (var key in week_total) {
    $("." + key).html(week_total[key]);
}
```

I am getting a `NaN` and thereforce every group has a `NaN`. Is this the right way of even using `week_total[group] = week_total[group] + work_minutes;`?

My script:

```js
drawCallback: function (settings) {
    var api   = this.api(), data;
    var rows  = api.rows({page: 'current'}).nodes();
    var last  = null;

    var week_total = new Array;

    api.column(weekColumn, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i) {
        var work_hours   = api.column(hourColumn).data()[i].split(':');
        var work_minutes = (+ work_hours[0]) * 60 + (+ work_hours[1]);

        week_total[group] = week_total[group] + work_minutes;

        if (last !== group) {
            $(rows).eq(i).before('<tr><td colspan="5">{{ trans('admin.worktime.field.week') }} ' + group + '</td><td colspan="3" style="font-style:italic;" class="' + group + '"></td></tr>');

            last = group;
        }
    });

    for (var key in week_total) {
        $("." + key).html(week_total[key]);
    }

    var array = {
        work_month: work_month,
        work_year: work_year
    };

    history.pushState(null, null, '?' + $.param(array));

    drawDataTable(this);
}
```

Comment: Where tour week_total was initialized and what in week_total[group] undefined?

Comment: @Sabik What do you mean? `week_total` is been initialized as `var week_total = new Array;` and been used in the `for (var key in week_total) {` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, problem is in not initialized week_total array.

Calculating should be like

```
week_total[group] = week_total[group]
    ? week_total[group] + work_minutes
    : work_minutes;
```

If week_total[group] is undefined then week_total[group] + 1 will be NaN

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on why I had the NaN.